# Time Conflicts in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do have two time StartDate1, EndDate1, StartDate2, EndDate2.

```
StartDate1 = 10:30 AM
EndDate1 = 12:00 PM 
StartDate2 = 9:00 AM
EndDate2 = 10:30 AM
```

Now through SQL query want to check times are overlapping or not. Please let me know SQL query. Thanks

Comment: Time periods are overlapping when the following predicate is true: `EndDate1 >= StartDate2 and EndDate2 >= StartDate1`

Answer (score 2):

I assume all four columns are in the same table. 
So you could simply select them like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE StartDate2 BETWEEN StartDate1 AND EndDate1
    OR EndDate2   BETWEEN StartDate1 AND EndDate1
    OR StartDate1 BETWEEN StartDate2 AND EndDate2
    OR EndDate1   BETWEEN StartDate2 AND EndDate2
```